# Sublists of a list in java

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, sublist

There are N buildings in a certain one-dimensional landscape. Each building has a height given by hi,i∈[1,N]. If you join K adjacent buildings, they will form a solid rectangle of area K×min(hi,hi+1,…,hi+k−1).

Given N buildings, find the greatest such solid area formed by consecutive buildings.

Input Format 
The first line contains N, the number of buildings altogether. 
The second line contains N space-separated integers, each representing the height of a building.

Output Format 
One integer representing the maximum area of rectangle formed.

Sample Input

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Sample Output

```
9
```

This is my code , i tried to cross check it but there was a problem with it , whenever i access a sublist , it is getting sorted automatically and their positions are aso getting changed in the original list

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

 public class Solution 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int n=sc.nextInt();

   List<Integer> al= new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        al.add(sc.nextInt());

  int i, c,min=0;

  for( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
  {

     for( i = c+1 ; i <= n ; i++ )
     {   
         System.out.println(" value of c is "+c+" value of i is "+i);
         List<Integer> X = al.subList(c,i);

         for(int j=0;j<X.size();j++)
             System.out.print(X.get(j)+" ");

         System.out.println();

         Collections.sort(X);

         for(int j=0;j<X.size();j++)
             System.out.print(X.get(j)+" ");

         System.out.println();

         int x=X.get(0);
         System.out.println("min value is "+x);
         int y=x*(X.size());
         System.out.println("projected value is "+y);

         if(y > min)
             min = y;

         System.out.println("modified value is "+min);

      }
   }

    System.out.println(min);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subList() method is actually explicitly documented to give you a *view* of the original:

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified
>        * {@code fromIndex}, inclusive, and {@code toIndex}, exclusive.  (If
>        * {@code fromIndex} and {@code toIndex} are equal, the returned list is
>        * empty.)  The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural
>        * changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.
>        * The returned list supports all of the optional list operations.

So subList() is not suitable if you want to modify it and not reflect the changes back to the original.

Instead make an explicit copy:

```
List<Integer> X = new ArrayList<>(al.subList(c,i));
```

Comment: do you suggest me to clear the sublist after using it , or is it not required as we are declaring it again so it would automatically clear it?

Comment: @coder101 Not sure what you're asking. Since the subList created from "al" only is accessible to the constructor for the new ArrayList, there is no way to clear it (and no need either, leave this to the GC). Or are you asking about *reusing* the ArrayList X? You could do that (create the X before the loop, then use clear() and addAll(subList) instead of new), but again no need to make it more complicated for no reason.

Comment: What is the difference between creating X in loop , and before the loop and which takes less time to execute?

Collections.sort() method took a lot of time to execute , but when i used a for loop to find minimum value it passed more number of test cases but not all 

What do you suggest me? It is not passing all test cases due to time out ( more thsn 4 seconds )

Comment: @coder101 If its about performance, it depends. I don't believe resue will get you much better performance - but trying is better than guessing. You would actually need to improve the calculation method, if you need to bring down execution time by an *order of magnitude*.

Comment: When i created the X before the loop, it is showing me IndexOutOfBoundsException error

Comment: @coder101 I broke my crystal ball, so you need to post the code and stacktrace.